# Calling a variable not working in kivy's kv-language

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

My question is this, after I set a variable on one screen how do I call it on another?

Here is the code for what I am trying to do:

main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

example.kv

```
#: import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager
#: set Question 'not working'

<Manager>
    transition: sm.FadeTransition()
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<FirstScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: txt
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: 'Press Me'
            on_release:
                Question = txt.text
                app.root.current = 'Next'

<SecondScreen>
    name: 'Next'
    Label:
        text: Question
```

When this is run everything works as it should. With one exception. The Label on SecondScreen reads "not working" when it should read whatever I type into the text input on FirstScreen. Why can I not accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide id tag and use ids method or ObjectProperty to reference the variables. Please refer to the two example below for details.

## Example 1 - Using ids method

An id is a weakref to the widget.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

### example.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: set Question 'not working'

<Manager>
    transition: FadeTransition()
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:
        id: second_screen

<FirstScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: txt
            text: "Working!"
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: 'Press Me'
            on_release:
                root.manager.ids.second_screen.ids.label.text = txt.text
                app.root.current = 'Next'

<SecondScreen>
    name: 'Next'
    Label:
        id: label
        text: Question
```

### Output - Using ids method

[image: Using ids method]

## Example 2 - Using ObjectProperty

The ‘best practice’ to use the ObjectProperty. This creates a direct reference, provides faster access and is more explicit.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    second_screen = ObjectProperty()


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    label = ObjectProperty()


class ObjectPropertyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ObjectPropertyApp().run()
```

### objectproperty.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: set Question 'not working'

<Manager>
    second_screen: second_screen
    transition: FadeTransition()
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:
        id: second_screen

<FirstScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: txt
            text: "Working!"
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: 'Press Me'
            on_release:
                root.manager.second_screen.label.text = txt.text
                app.root.current = 'Next'

<SecondScreen>
    name: 'Next'
    label: label
    Label:
        id: label
        text: Question
```

### Output - Using ObjectProperty

[image: Using ObjectProperty]

Comment: It works great, thank you, i wasn't even thinking about ids, because they are _weakref_ and easily overlooked.

Comment: You are right, an id is a weakref. The ‘best practice’ to use the ObjectProperty. This creates a direct reference, provides faster access and is more explicit. I have added another example using ObjectProperty. Please refer to it for details.